# How to pass an angular object value from HTML to AngularJS controller as parameter

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a list as below

```
$scope.fileUploadTypesList ={'abc','def'}
```

I am declaring a list as below

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="list in fileUploadTypesList track by $index">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="{{list}}Upload">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 imgHolder">
                            <h5 class="text-muted"
                                style="position:absolute;top:30%;left:20%;right:20%;text-align: center;">
                                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-2x"></i><br /> Attach {{list}}
                            </h5>
                            <img class="center fileUploadImage" />
                            <input name="{{list}}Upload" type="file" 
                                   class="fileUpload" accept="image/*"
                                   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files,{{list}})">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And my controller function is as below

```
 $scope.selectFileforUpload = function (file, fname) {
        console.log("File Select event:"+ fname);
        $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = file[0];
        $scope.SaveFile(fname);
    };
```

Now `fname` is not able to receive value from `{{list}}`
Its giving me the following console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`
How do I send the `{{list}}` value to the parameter

Using `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files,{{list}})"` I am trying to send the `{{list}}` value

`fname` is the varieble that is supposed to receive the `{{list}}` value

Comment: fname? Can you attach more code.

Comment: indeed, but you don't need the `{{}}` because you are passing this value through a function which is already in your scope. You should only pass `item` instead of `{{item}}`

Comment: Its sending 'null' if I use only list

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the item value you will need to access the element's scope using

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="{{list}}Upload" 
  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileforUpload(this.files,
    angular.element(this).scope().item)">


$scope.selectFileforUpload = function(files, list) {
    console.log(list);
    console.log(files[0].name);
    console.log(files[0]);
};
```

here is a working example.  http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/QEpLRa

Comment: Did this answer help you?